# Getting error while executing the script :system.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException:

Tags: powershell, api, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

```
$API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx"

# Source image files
$ImageFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\sam\Desktop\jpeg\* -filter *).Name

$uploadedFiles = @()

try {
foreach ($imageFile in $ImageFiles ) {
    # 1a. RETRIEVE THE PRESIGNED URL TO UPLOAD THE FILE.
   
    # Prepare URL for `Get Presigned URL` API call
    $query = "https://api.pdf.co/v1/file/upload/get-presigned-url? 
contenttype=application/octet-stream&name=" + `
        [IO.Path]::GetFileName($imageFile)
    $query = [System.Uri]::EscapeUriString($query)

    # Execute request
    $jsonResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{ "x-api-key" = $API_KEY } -Uri 
$query

    if ($jsonResponse.error -eq $false) {
        # Get URL to use for the file upload
        $uploadUrl = $jsonResponse.presignedUrl
        # Get URL of uploaded file to use with later API calls
        $uploadedFileUrl = $jsonResponse.url

        # 1b. UPLOAD THE FILE TO CLOUD.

        $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Put -Headers @{ "x-api-key" = $API_KEY; "content-type" 
  = "application/octet-stream" } -InFile $imageFile -Uri $uploadUrl
       
        if ($r.StatusCode -eq 200) {
            # Keep uploaded file URL
            $uploadedFiles += $uploadedFileUrl
        }
        else {
            # Display request error status
            Write-Host $r.StatusCode + " " + $r.StatusDescription
        }
        }
    else {
        # Display service reported error
        Write-Host $jsonResponse.message
    }
    }

    if ($uploadedFiles.length -gt 0) {
    # 2. CREATE PDF DOCUMENT FROM UPLOADED IMAGE FILES

    # Prepare URL for `DOC To PDF` API call
    $query = "https://api.pdf.co/v1/pdf/convert/from/image"

    # Prepare request body (will be auto-converted to JSON by Invoke-RestMethod)
    # See documentation: https://apidocs.pdf.co
    $body = @{
        "name" = $(Split-Path $DestinationFile -Leaf)
        "url" = $uploadedFiles -join ","
    } | ConvertTo-Json
   
    # Execute request
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Headers @{ "x-api-key" = $API_KEY; "Content- 
 Type" = "application/json" } -Body $body -Uri $query
   
    $jsonResponse = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
   
    if ($jsonResponse.error -eq $false) {
        # Get URL of generated PDF file
        $resultFileUrl = $jsonResponse.url;

       

        $DestinationFile = "C:\Users\sam\Desktop\pdf\$imagefile.split('.')[0]"
       
        # Download PDF file
        Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{ "x-api-key" = $API_KEY } -OutFile $DestinationFile -Uri 
   $resultFileUrl

        Write-Host "Generated PDF file saved as `"$($DestinationFile)`" file."
    }
    else {
        # Display service reported error
        Write-Host $jsonResponse.message
    }  
    }
     }
   catch {
# Display request error
Write-Host $_.Exception
  }


  PS C:\Users\nikhileshwar.yerragu> C:\Users\nikhileshwar.yerragu\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\JPEGTOPDF.ps1
```

System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException: Cannot find path 'C:\Users\nikhileshwa
r.yerragu\arsen-vivcharyk-dmRB6RXRpFk-unsplash.jpg' because it does not exist.
at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.ExpandMshGlobPath(String path, Boolean
allowNonexistingPaths, PSDriveInfo drive, ContainerCmdletProvider provider, CmdletProvider
Context context)
at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.ResolveDriveQualifiedPath(String path,
CmdletProviderContext context, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, CmdletProvider& providerInst
ance)
at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedMonadPathsFromMonadPath(Strin
g path, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, CmdletProviderContext context, CmdletProvider& prov
iderInstance)
at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedProviderPathsFromMonadPath(St
ring path, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, CmdletProviderContext context, ProviderInfo& pro
vider, CmdletProvider& providerInstance)
at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedProviderPathsFromMonadPath(St
ring path, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, ProviderInfo& provider, CmdletProvider& provider
Instance)
at System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet.GetResolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(String path,
ProviderInfo& provider)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ValidateParameters()

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

Replace:

```
$ImageFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\sam\Desktop\jpeg\* -filter *).Name
```

with:

```
$ImageFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\sam\Desktop\jpeg\* -filter *).FullName
```

which can be simplified to:

```
$ImageFiles = (Get-ChildItem -File -LiteralPath C:\Users\sam\Desktop\jpeg).FullName
```

---

The error message self-evidently tells you that file `C:\Users\nikhileshwa r.yerragu\arsen-vivcharyk-dmRB6RXRpFk-unsplash.jpg` doesn't exist, so that's where the troubleshooting needs to start.

The source is `$imageFile`, which is used as the iteration variable to loop over the elements stored in array `$ImageFiles` using a `foreach` statement.

Looking at how  `$ImageFile` is populated - `(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\sam\Desktop\jpeg\* -filter *).Name` - we can conclude that it contains an array of file *names*, *without path information*.

This means that when you pass `-InFile $imageFile` to your `Invoke-WebRequest` call, it will only succeed if the current location (directory) *happens to be* `C:\Users\sam\Desktop\jpeg`.

Instead of relying what the current location happens to be, populate the `$ImageFiles` array with *full paths*, as shown at the top.

Comment: Thank you so much it solved the issue . Am facing with another issue now .Basically this script converts bulk number of JPEG images to PDF format .Its working initially but later when i execute the script it is getting failed by this error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." . I googled this issue and added these two lines at the beginning of the script

Comment: #[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocolNet.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 .Even after adding these two am getting the same old error  .Could you please help me with this issue

Comment: Glas to hear the initial issue is solved, @nikhileshwary. If you have a _follow-up_ question, please create a _new_ question post. However, I encourage you to search for existing answers first.